# How to remove --enable-preview in Java 16?

Tags: java, ant, javac, java-16, preview-feature

To use records with JDK 15, I used to compile with arguments `--enable-preview --release 15` passed to javac on my Ant build.  Everything compiled and run fine.

When using JDK 16, if I compile with the same arguments, I get

> error: invalid source release 15 with --enable-preview   (preview
> language features are only supported for release 16)

Records are a standard feature of JDK 16, so I expected that I should compile without those arguments.  However, If I remove them, I get

> Foo.class uses preview features of Java SE 15.   (use --enable-preview
> to allow loading of classfiles which contain preview features)

And Ant reports a compilation failure:

> Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1425)

So, its a compilation failure with the flags and without them.  What's wrong?

Comment: "error: invalid source release 15 with --enable-preview (preview language features are only supported for release 16)" Not sure about ant but you are trying to compile this class with Java 16 compiler along with `--enable-preview --release 15`. You can do this directly without `--enable-preview` when using Java 16. Those parameters are required only when using Java 15. However, if you would like to use Java 16 preview features then do `javac --enable-preview --release 16 ...`

Answer (score 5):

> error: invalid source release 15 with --enable-preview (preview
> language features are only supported for release 16)

Since you are using JDK-16, you have to use 16 as the value of `--release` (usually for any feature which is available in JDK-16 as a preview feature). Thus, the following will work for you:

```
javac --enable-preview --release 16 MyClass.java
```

However, [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) is a standard feature in Java-16 and therefore you do not need to compile your code with `--enable-preview` parameter. You can compile your code without using this parameter i.e.

```
javac MyClass.java
```

> Foo.class uses preview features of Java SE 15. (use --enable-preview
> to allow loading of classfiles which contain preview features)

This is not a compile-time error. You get it when trying to run a .java class compiled with `--enable-preview` parameter, directly. You can run it as

```
java --enable-preview MyClass
```

> Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1425)

You need to update your `JAVA_HOME` setting to point to JDK-16 in order for `ant` to use JDK-16.

Comment: By the way, Java 16 offers the [*sealed classes*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397) feature in its second preview. So if you want to try that feature, you’ll need to enable preview-mode as discussed in this correct Answer, but for Java 16 rather than Java 15.

Comment: But why then Ant says "Compile failed" and doesn't say so when compiling with JDK 15?

Comment: @ARX - You need to update your `JAVA_HOME` setting to JDK-16. I missed mentioning it in my answer earlier. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.