# Java Error: Could not find or load main class, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, runtime-error, classpath, javacompiler, java-package

#### Compiled

I've compiled the java code, but I'm not able to run it. I compiled the code with the following:

```
javac -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java
```

Currently, I'm getting this output:

```
Note: EnduserCredentialExample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

#### Tried running the compiled class

I also tried running with another approach:

```
java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample
```

Which, unfortunately, produces the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class EnduserCredentialExample Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExample (wrong name: EnduserCredentialExample)
```

And then I also tried running the code using .java (I added **.java** to it):

```
java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java
```

But this worked when running the normal java code but when I tried running the compiled class, I got this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class EnduserCredentialExample Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExample (wrong name: EnduserCredentialExample)
```

Comment: Looks like your class argument should be `com.quotemedia.streamer.client.example.EnduserCredentialExample`

Comment: All details relevant to your question must be in the question.  Hint: your question will become meaningless to others the instant that your google drive links are disabled.

Comment: @g00se When I try below command 

`java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:." com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExampl`

Im getting following error,

Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.quotemedia.streamer.client.example.EnduserCredentialExample
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExample (class file version 61.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'

Comment: Navethaneeth - You don't get it.  Please don't give us links to your Google Drive. Not in the question.  Not in the comments.  **Not at all**.

Comment: You didn't use what I gave you

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making a number of mistakes ...

Firstly you appear to be ignoring warnings about unchecked / unsafe conversions:

```
Note: EnduserCredentialExample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

You need to do what the message says.  Recompile that class with the `-Xlint:unchecked` option.  Then read the error messages and correct your source code.

(Hint: I am NOT going to look at your Google drive to figure out errors are.  You know what you need to do about that.  I have told you ... twice already!!)

---

Next we have this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class EnduserCredentialExample 
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExample 
    (wrong name: EnduserCredentialExample)
```

That means that there is a mismatch between the package name of the class and its pathname in the file system.  See this Q&A for an explanation:

- [NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/)

---

Finally we have this error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.quotemedia.streamer.client.example.EnduserCredentialExample java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
Preview features are not enabled for com/quotemedia/streamer/client/example/EnduserCredentialExample (class file version 61.65535). 
Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

It appears that you have (previously) compiled `EnduserCredentialExample` with Java 17 preview features enabled.  That's OK ... but you also need to include `--enable-preview` in the `java` command line options when you load and run the class.  This Q&A may help you understand:

- [How to remove --enable-preview in Java 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164057)

Unless you are intentionally using preview features in your code, it is inadvisable to enable them at compile time.